# How to pass a templated function parameter with a subclass of the templated type in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Compiling the following contrived example:

```
class Base
{};

class Derived : public Base
{};

template< typename T >
class A
{};

class B
{
public:

    static void f( const A< Base >& ) {}
};

int main()
{
    A< Base > tb;
    A< Derived > td;

    B::f( tb );
    B::f( td );

    return 0;
}
```

using g++-8 gives me the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'B::f(A<Derived>&)'
 B::f( td );
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'A<Derived>' to 'const A<Base>&'
```

Why?

Since `Derived` *is-a* `Base` and it doesn't override any of `Base`'s stuff, why can't I give a `Derived` in the place of a `Base` in the templated function parameter?

Comment: `A< Base >` and `A< Derived >` are distinct, unrelated classes. There's no conversion between them. There doesn't have to be any similarity between them at all - they could have different members entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that `Derived` is derived from `Base`, but that doesn't mean that `A<Derived>` must therefore be derived from `A<Base>`. C++ templates don't work this way.

All that `A<Derived>` is, is a class, instantiated by the `A` template. You could've simply declared:

```
class A_Derived {

     // ...

};
```

With the same members (if it had any), and pretty much got the same results. Same for `A<Base>`. With nothing else in the picture, the two classes have absolutely nothing to do with each other, whatsoever. You can draw a mental picture here, as if you made the following declarations:

```
class A_Derived {

};
```

and

```
class A_Base {

};
```

Which is pretty much what this is history. Do you see `A_Derived` being explicitly derived from `A_Base` here? Obviously not. If something expects a reference or a pointer to `A_Base`, you cannot give it `A_Derived`, because the two classes have absolutely nothing to do with each other. They are independent classes.

P.S. You could declare an explicit specialization of `A<Derived>` as being derived from `A<Base>`, if you so wish, but specialization is a completely different topic...

Answer (score 1):

Template instances, like `A<Base>` and `A<Derived>`, are different types. In particular they do not have any inheritance relationship even if `Base` and `Derived` do.

There are quite a few ways you can make what you want work.

First, you could make `A<Derived>` explicitly derive from `A<Base>`, but that means adding a whole class definition.

```
template<>
class A<Derived> : public A<Base>
{};
```

Second, you can provide an implicit conversion from `A<Derived>` to `A<Base>` in the form of a constructor template. You can use `std::enable_if` and `std::is_base_of` to only allow `A<T>` where `T` is derived from `Base`, or directly `std::is_same` if you only want to consider this particular `Derived` type.

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    template<typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<T, U>>>
    A(A<U> const& other);
};
```

Third, you can provide an implicit conversion in the form of an operator template, in much the same way.

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    template<typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<U, T>>>
    operator U();
};
```

Fourth, you can make `f` a function template and restrict what types it takes.

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>>>
static void f(A<T> const& a);
```